# Is it possible to get reports by filtering using power bi rest api?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

Is it possible to get reports by filtering using power bi rest api? I want to embed power bi reports filtering by records. I can't see any option on power bi rest api, then how to get all reports by filter and embed reports in my application?

Since I am using powerbi.js as javascript client so below is my sample code:
https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript

```
    var tokenType = 'embed';

    // Get models. models contains enums that can be used.
    var models = window['powerbi-client'].models;

    // We give All permissions to demonstrate switching between View and 
    //Edit mode and saving report.
    var permissions = models.Permissions.All;

    var config = {
        type: 'report',
        tokenType: tokenType == '0' ? models.TokenType.Aad : 
        models.TokenType.Embed,
        accessToken: txtAccessToken,
        embedUrl: txtEmbedUrl,
        id: txtEmbedReportId,
        permissions: permissions,
        settings: {
            filterPaneEnabled: true,
            navContentPaneEnabled: true
        }
    };

    // Get a reference to the embedded report HTML element
    var embedContainer = $('#embedContainer')[0];

    // Embed the report and display it within the div container.
    var report = (<any>window).powerbi.embed(embedContainer, config);
```

Comment: Could you explain what `get all reports by filter` means, please?

Comment: for example, I have a report with dynamics crm account id and sales amount fields, now I want to filter report by account id, how to do such kind of filter in power bi report?

Comment: I do not understand how is this related to Power BI REST API. Do you want to pass filters in the URL? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-url-filters

Comment: using Power BI REST API I can get embed url, is it possible to pass query parameter with this embed url?

Answer (score 0):

When you are embedding a report, you can use the [Embed Configuration](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Embed-Configuration-Details) to apply filters when the report is loaded. You can also change the filters dynamically later.

Here is a quote from [filters wiki](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Filters):

> Filters are JavaScript objects that have a special set of properties. Currently, there are five types of filters: `Basic`, `Advanced`, `Relative Date`, `Top N` and `Include/Exclude`, which match the types of filters you can create through the filter pane. There are corresponding interfaces `IBasicFilter`, `IAdvancedFilter`, `IRelativeDateFilter`, `ITopNFilter` and `IIncludeExcludeFilter`, which describe their required properties.

For example, your filter can be constructed like this:

```
const basicFilter: pbi.models.IBasicFilter = {
  $schema: "http://powerbi.com/product/schema#basic",
  target: {
    table: "Sales",
    column: "AccountId"
  },
  operator: "In",
  values: [1,2,3],
  filterType: pbi.models.FilterType.BasicFilter
}
```

You should pass this filter in report's configuration `filters` property.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I am using powerbi.js client and added my sample code in my post, please check my edit there.

Comment: so instead of pbi.models.IBasicFilter will it work using my code like: models.IBasicFilter ? since I have set models like: var models = window['powerbi-client'].models;

Comment: As far as I understand your question, after constructed the sample filter as shown above, you just need to add `filters: [basicFilter]` to `config`. And yes, it looks you can omit `pbi` and use `models.IBasicFilter`.

Comment: I am getting this error after added filter on config: angular.min.js:123 Possibly unhandled rejection: [{"message":"filters property is invalid"}]

Comment: @user10496245 did you fix this? I had filters working and now suddenly they no longer work. Same error "filters property is invalid"

Comment: So, I'd like to use the PowerBI REST API shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/reports/exporttofile) (the one you send GET/POST requests to, not the C# or Javascript API). 
How can I send filter parameters via this API?