# Upload value list text file on power bi filter

Tags: powerbi

I have created a power bi pro (online) report.

This report contains a filter. This is a basic text Input, linked on a field.

Here is what i want to do: i want to type several values (with a separator) and I want to filter all rows whose value match.

I have a very large number of possible values. The user can type about 100 values. Is it possible for the user to send a text file instead of typing values in filter ?

Thanks

Comment: No it's not possible to send a text file to the filter. You'll have to add them as normal.

Comment: Is there a reason a dropdown slicer wouldn't work for this?

Comment: I have a very big number of items to show into the dropdown and a very big number of items to check for the user. Is there a way to code some c# into the report ?

Comment: C# - no. JavaScript - yes. If you [embed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56409362/is-there-any-way-to-embed-power-bi-reports-and-dashboards-in-vb-net-or-c-sharp-d/56418991#56418991) the report in your application, you can add [filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53720478/is-it-possible-to-get-reports-by-filtering-using-power-bi-rest-api/53723137#53723137) to it.

Comment: Javascript will works both on Power BI Desktop and Power BI pro (online) ? Thanks

Comment: I have read some documentation and what I see is this JavaScript api is « outside » the report. Is there something i have missed ? Is it possible to embed javascript code inside a report ? Thanks

Comment: Sadly you're not able to put Javascript in the report. As @AndreyNikolov pointed out, Javascript is an option if you use Power BI Embedded. There might be some custom visuals out there that might work in your case, like this: https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/power-bi-visuals/WA104381413?tab=Overview

Comment: And is it possible to make a predictive text box input ? Exactly like tags input on stack overflow?